# Modal window for edit model in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, modal-dialog, sonata-admin

How can I set-up the an Admin class in SonataAdminBundle, to display the form for adding/editing an entity in a modal window? Like below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually you can do it yourself.

1. Add in your config service

   ```
   calls:
   - [ setTemplate, [list, AcmeYourBundle:Your:base_list.html.twig]]
   - [ setTemplate, [edit, AcmeYourBundle:Your:base_edit.html.twig]]
   ```
2. In your admin bundle add custom templete in configureListFields

   ```
   protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper) {
     $listMapper
       ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
         'actions' => array(
           'edit' => array('template' => 'AcmeYourBundle:Your:_action_edit.html.twig'),
         )
       ));
   }
   ```
3. _action_edit.html.twig

   ```
   {% if admin.hasRoute('edit') and admin.id(object) and admin.isGranted('EDIT', object)%}
     <a class="edit sonata-action-element" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('edit', object) }}">
       <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
       {{ 'link_action_edit'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
     </a>
   {% endif %}
   ```
4. Add javascript code in base_list.html.twig

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('a.edit').click(function() {   //bind handlers
           var url = $(this).attr('href');
           showDialog(url);
           return false;
       });

       $("#targetDiv").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         height: 700,
         width: 950,
         modal: true
       });

       function showDialog(url) {  
         $("#targetDiv").load(url);
         $("#targetDiv").dialog("open");
       }
     });

   </script>
   ```
5. Done ! Enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported yet, this is a planned feature but no ETA for now.